# Excel Macro to create a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I don't have a problem that needs fixing since I just forced-solved it by copying others, but I'm curious how to read this and why it's different than what tutorials show:

When I recorded a macro to create a pivot table, it codes it this way (snip):

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TABXXX").PivotTables("PivotTable9"). _
    PivotCache.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=7
```

But everyone says to have this (note that I changed the source and pivot worksheets and calculate the last row # following internet directions):

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "'" & dataWS & "'!A1:K" & lastrow, Version:=7).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "'" & pivotWS & "'!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=7
```

Why does my recorded macro show up the way it does?

Comment: Your recorded code snippet is working off an existing `PivotCache`.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, pivot tables can be built on data that exists in many different places.  The data could be on an Excel worksheet, or it could be in a text file, or it could be in a database.  As a result, the first step in making a pivot table is to get a copy of the data in a standard format, regardless of where the data comes from.  This is what a PivotCache is.  So, if you record yourself making the first pivot table from data in Excel, the code will show the creation of the PivotCache object.

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(...
```

However, when you build a subsequent pivot table on data that already has a pivot cache built, the recorder will identify the existing cache:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TABXXX").PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotCache...
```

Which means, find the PivotCache used for a pivot table named "PivotTable9" on a worksheet named "TABXXX" in the activbe workbook.

Comment: Ok, OK. So if I had instead started recording the macro first thing when I opened up the file (instead of doing a practice run first), it would be more like the typical internet format?

Comment: I'm certain that would be the case.